# How can I Case-update based on a multi-index update statement?

Tags: python, peewee

Supposing I have a model class:

```
class A(Model):
    key1 = ...
    key2 = ...
    value1 = ...
```

I'd like to:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=..., index=['key1', 'key2'], columns=['value1'])
Model.update(value1=Case((A.key1, A.key2)), list(df.items()).where(...).execute()
```

but this doesn't work because `Case` seems to accept only a single key, at least I couldn't find such detail in the documentation.

I need to lookup the error I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the original poster's request, here is how you would do it with row tuples:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class Number(db.Model):
    v1 = IntegerField()
    v2 = IntegerField()
    label = TextField(default='')

Number.create_table()

for i in range(1, 5):
    Number.create(v1=i, v2=i)

label_expr = Case(Tuple(Number.v1, Number.v2), (
    (Tuple(1, 1), 'one'),
    (Tuple(2, 2), 'two'),
    (Tuple(3, 3), 'three')), 'a lot')
Number.update(label=label_expr).execute()

for n in Number:
    print(n.v1, n.v2, n.label)
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs should be instructive. http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Case

Example of using Case with update:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class Number(db.Model):
    val = IntegerField()
    label = TextField(default='')

Number.create_table()

for i in range(1, 5):
    Number.create(val=i)

label_expr = Case(Number.val, (
    (1, 'one'),
    (2, 'two'),
    (3, 'three')), 'a lot')
Number.update(label=label_expr).execute()

for n in Number:
    print(n.val, n.label)
# 1 one
# 2 two
# 3 three
# 4 a lot
```

More examples:

```
class Number(db.Model):
    val = IntegerField()

num_as_str = Case(Number.val, (
    (1, 'one'),
    (2, 'two'),
    (3, 'three')), 'a lot')

query = Number.select(Number.val, num_as_str.alias('num_str'))

# The above is equivalent to:
# SELECT "val",
#   CASE "val"
#       WHEN 1 THEN 'one'
#       WHEN 2 THEN 'two'
#       WHEN 3 THEN 'three'
#       ELSE 'a lot' END AS "num_str"
# FROM "numbers"

num_as_str = Case(None, (
    (Number.val == 1, 'one'),
    (Number.val == 2, 'two'),
    (Number.val == 3, 'three')), 'a lot')
query = Number.select(Number.val, num_as_str.alias('num_str'))

# The above is equivalent to:
# SELECT "val",
#   CASE
#       WHEN "val" = 1 THEN 'one'
#       WHEN "val" = 2 THEN 'two'
#       WHEN "val" = 3 THEN 'three'
#       ELSE 'a lot' END AS "num_str"
# FROM "numbers"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. My question is referring to the case where I need to match rows based on multiple columns (see example in OP key1 and key2 to update value1). Is that supported or not?

Comment: Yeah you can peewee's `Tuple()` to represent a row tuple for the case conditions.

Comment: You're comment would be the answer actually :D

Comment: Here's a new answer. I'm going to leave the original in case anyone else stumbles here from google, though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77097558/254346